# PhoneGap-iOS, how to show dialog with red button?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am working with Phonegap on iOS, and here is the codes to show the dialog:

```
navigator.notification.confirm(
              'Which color do you like most?'
            , confirmCB
            , 'Title | Confirm'
            , 'Green,Red'
        );
```

I want to show a confirmation dialog with red cancel button but I don't know how. Please helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible with phonegap.

`navigator.notification.confirm` uses the native `UIAlertView`, and the `UIAlertView` buttons are blue/gray, and the cancel button darker blue/gray

You can try to create a plugin with this library [BlockAlerts And ActionSheets](https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets)

Or use a javascript/css alert replacements

Comment: Thanks. The acceptable solution is that create a custom popup/dialog with jQueryMobile.